# Keyboard problem on Lichee Pi Zero with kernel 5.2+

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, cortex-a

My question is about Lichee Pi Zero board (based on Allwinner/Sunxi V3s SoC).

Initially I used pre-built Linux image (kernel 4.10.02), it has no built-in Wi-Fi support (for Realtek 8327BS chip), so I downloaded the latest kernel version from [here](https://github.com/Lichee-Pi/linux/tree/zero-5.2.y) and built it with the default settings.

LCD is ok, Wi-fi looks good too (LED is blinkikng), but **I cannot use keyboard anymore** - there is no reaction from OS, when I connect something to USB (no message and no input from keyboard).

Hardware is OK and works good with the old Linux image.
I have also tried the latest kernel from [kernel.org](http://kernel.org) with the same bad result.

Please help to understand the reason. I suppose bad settings, but HID supoort is enabled.

**Update 1.**
I establish connection through UART. As I see, some USB features are detected during boot:
[image]

[image]

I'm able to load some drivers using `insmod` also:
[image]
Unfortunately, Linux still does not recognize any USB Device. I have connected mouse, keyboard, hub, mass storage and got no reaction from OS. It looks like devices do not get power (there is no light from mouse).

**Update 2.**
The best way I have found at the moment is to use [buildroot-licheepi-zero](https://github.com/Squonk42/buildroot-licheepi-zero).
It's very easy to use:

```
make licheepi_zero_defconfig
make menuconfig (optional)
make
```

After many-hour wainting I got the sdcard.img. It includes all neccessary files (zImage, RootFS, u-boot.bin, etc) and could be placed to SD with linux `dd` or [etcher](https://etcher.io/).
Linux boots successfully, but you can use terminal only through UART, as there is no LCD output.
You can put LCD itself to work:

```
make uboot-menuconfig
```

[image]

```
make
```

BUT **there is still no user login prompt** on the LCD after boot. So I need to log in and put command through UART.
Please share suggestion if any.

**Update 3.**
The change below enables login prompt on LCD (and disables it through UART):

`make menuconfig`
[image]

Now we are able to use Wi-Fi:

1. `insmod /lib/modules/4.14.14-licheepi-zero/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8723bs/r8723bs.ko`
2. `ifconfig wlan0 up`
3. edit file `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` to add your Wi-Fi SSID and PSK
4. `wpa_supplicant -B -d -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`
5. `udhcpc -i wlan0`

Connection is established now, we can `ping` and so on.

There is still **the question** - how to enable full-functional terminal both on LCD and UART.

Many thanks!
With regards,
Maksim

Comment: Sounds like USB support is missing completely. (I never heard that Linux kernel for ARM works out of the box, you always have to patch. And I recommend to try vanilla kernel which is v5.8 / v5/9-rc4 as of today)

Comment: What do you mean by "default settings"? Did you use `licheepi_zero_defconfig` as a make target?

Comment: @IanAbbott, yes, you are right. Then I run 'make ARCH=arm menuconfig' and build kernel after it. By the way, I ran the same procedure for kernel 4.10.15 and I got keyboard support, but no Wi-Fi, because appropriate driver is absent in that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to use **Buildroot**.
Please check updates at topic start for details.

Comment: There is a dtb patch to enable the usb in a more common form.  It is adapted from the licheepi nano.  I cannot post all the lines here: https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/linux-usb/patch/20200331170219.267732-6-thirtythreeforty@gmail.com/